# Geostyler plugin for GeoServer version 2.23.2

Tags: geoserver

I am interested to try Geostyler plugin for GeoServer: https://geostyler.org

Instruction say:
You will need to download a version that is compatible to your GeoServer version.

But apparently the latest Geostyler version is for GeoServer 2.22, while I need it for 2.23.
There is no GeoStyler plugin installation file here: https://build.geoserver.org/geoserver/2.23.x/community-latest/

Can it be used for GeoServer 2.23? Did anyone try?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that GeoStyler's community module was kicked out of the build as no one was looking after it, and from their web site it seems as though you can connect to GeoServer via the REST API now so there is no need for a plugin any longer.